# "Dual Clanning" detector,Will not post. I cannot figure out how to update this code to Discord.js V14

Tags: discord.js, bots

The code does not work because it is very outdated and doesnt work with discord.js v14

```
module.exports = {
  name: "presenceUpdate",
  once: false,
  async execute(oldPresence, newPresence) {
    try {
      const memberId = newPresence?.member?.id;
      const serverName = newPresence?.activities[0]?.name;
      const serverInfo = newPresence?.activities[0]?.details;
      const statusType = newPresence?.activities[0]?.type;

      const testEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor("#00BFC0")
        .setTitle("W.E.T Dual Clanning Logs")
        .addFields(
          { name: "User's ID:", value: memberId },
          { name: "Member:", value: `<@${memberId}>` },
          { name: "Server Name:", value: serverName },
          { name: "Server Info:", value: serverInfo }
        )
        .setFooter({
          text: `W.E.T Dual Clanning Detection`,
          iconURL: `https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1055320525506871306/1204989075661258762/W.E.T_Logo.png?ex=65d6bc87&is=65c44787&hm=15eb47afb1fb3acfa378c363f5f75064865a665551576a6d61b1ecefca182a71&S`,
        });

      if (memberId && serverInfo !== undefined && serverName !== undefined) {
        const testArr = serverName.toLowerCase().split(" ");
        let exitElemCount = 0;

        for (const server of serverNames) {
          if (testArr.includes(server.toLowerCase())) {
            exitElemCount++;
          }
        }

        const strArr = serverInfo.toLowerCase().split(" ");

        for (const server of serverNames) {
          if (strArr.includes(server.toLowerCase())) {
            exitElemCount++;
          }
        }

        let exitElem = "false";

        if (testArr.length > 10) {
          if (exitElemCount <= 2) {
            exitElem = "true";
          }
        } else if (testArr.length > 2 && testArr.length <= 10) {
          if (exitElemCount <= 1) {
            exitElem = "true";
          }
        } else if (testArr.length <= 2) {
          if (exitElemCount <= 0) {
            exitElem = "true";
          }
        }

        if (exitElem === "true" && !statusType.includes("CUSTOM")) {
          newPresence.guild.channels.cache
            .get(channelConfig)
            .send({ content: `<@&${roleConfig}>`, embeds: [testEmbed] });
        }
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  },
};
```

I have tried using this to essentially role mention and send an embed to a specific channel in order to ensure that my members are not on any non-approved servers. I have updated what I could think of but am unsure of the rest. Any Help would be greatly appreciated